# Why was my last flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I've recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17629454/1841194) to my question. But my flag was declined. In my opinion that answer is both wrong and have content and length issues.

Now I wonder why this flag was declined? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you flagged was in fact just that, an answer. It may be incorrect, but it's still an answer, not a comment or question.

The flag reason really says it all:

> *"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be **an edit, a comment, another question,** or deleted altogether."*

Moderator flags are not intended to be used on "Incorrect" answers. In that case, downvote, maybe even comment, and move on.

Comment: Should I flag it as very low quality answer?

Comment: @ABFORCE: no. That's meant for answers that are, for example, nearly impossible to read. "Bad" answers are supposed to be downvoted. You can comment on it to explain the downvote, then...

Comment: As you said _ ... It should possibly be a comment ..._ this answer should be post as a comment not?

Comment: @ABFORCE: The post we're talking about is an answer. It may be incorrect, but it's still an attempt to answer the question. The reason I quoted that flag reason, if because it does not apply to the answer, for the bolded reasons.

Comment: But this answer has very low quality and small length

Comment: Some questions only need short answers.

Answer (score 2):

> just try height:100% in style tag

[answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628388/how-to-adjust-height-of-a-html-element-to-cover-all-free-spaces-of-its-parent/17629454#17629454)

that ^ is an answer. So you incorrectly flagged it as not an answer.

There really is no such thing as **length** issues when it comes to flagging as NAA.

For example :

> No

Could be an answer to a closed ended question.

You still should not flag as NAA if the answer is incorrect. Normally you should just downvote it, and leave a comment explaining why it's wrong if you want to.

Comment: But this answer is wrong as you can its comments

Comment: Just _"No"_ Is never a good answer.